# Copying DynamoDB table of one account to another DynamoDB table in different account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm setting up a serverless architecture and moving my old platform to new account and for this, I am using DynamoDB and Lambda, I have a table A in account 1 and I have to move everything in A to table B in Account 2.
So far I have created the IAM roles and defined all the policies for Cross account. I am stuck at the Python code in lambda function, I used STS for providing a temporary set of credentials to my Account B. So my question is

How do you GET everything in old Dynamo table and move it to the new one and PUT it there using lambda, Whats the code will look like?
What I can think of is that I can do `table.get_ item` and `table.put_item` but the thing is that the New Table is blank right now and how do I fetch the whole table, plus this is all written in lambda function using Python.

So far what I have done is : 
I Assumed a role in the new account.
I created a STS.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):


client = boto3.client('sts')
sts_response = client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::<043151570368>:role/Test-DynamoDB',                              
                                  RoleSessionName='AssumePocRole', DurationSeconds=900)
dynamodb = boto3.resource(service_name='dynamodb', region_name=<region>,
                          aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                          aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey',
                          aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

Comment: Is this a one-time migration of the table? And why do you want to do this in Lambda, which seems quite inappropriate for this task?

Comment: So, the previous architecture is built by a group of people and I am taking over the whole lot. Lambda seems like the easiest way right now as I want to keep on updating it as soon as change occurs in the table. So, It will be a continuous flow.
I still have some requirement of the old table so I can't completely delete it but I want to build a new one so that I can integrate that with the new architecture. Any better or alternative solution you have?

Comment: [have you read this article?](https://medium.com/@avinash.singhal/migrating-dynamodb-from-one-aws-account-to-another-with-zero-downtime-40826157844c)

Comment: If you want to keep the destination table in sync item by item with the source table then you should look at DynamoDB Streams. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607592/copy-dynamodb-table-to-another-aws-account-without-s3

Comment: I haven't, but thanks for sharing, this seems like something I can do. 
I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, look at this question, this has other options and many code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607592/copy-dynamodb-table-to-another-aws-account-without-s3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy dynamoDB table to another aws account without S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607592/copy-dynamodb-table-to-another-aws-account-without-s3)

Comment: Thanks Guys, Appreciate it. Really helpful.