# Simultaneously accessing two dynamodb tables belonging to different accounts using assume role does not work

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have a java application running in ECS in which I want to read data from table in account 1 (source_table) and write it to a table in account 2 (destination_table).  I created two dynamodb clients with  different credential providers - for source_table client I'm using an `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` with the arn of a role in account 1; for destination client I'm using `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`.

The assume role bit works and I'm able to read using the source client but using the destination client does not work - it still tries to use the assumed role credentials when trying to write to  destination_table and fails with unauthorized error (assumed-role is not authorized to perform Put Item).

I tried using `EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper` on the destination client but same error.

Should this work?  Or are the credentials shared under the hood which makes it impossible to have two different `AWSCredentialProvider`s running simultaneously like this?

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43612035/2918442) answer which uses static credentials and apparently works, so I'm at a loss why this doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your actual code -- or better, a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), _in your question,_ formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from AWS support.  It was a problem with my IAM configuration on the role in account 2.  I was misled by the error message which said 'assumed-role is not authorized to perform Put Item' when in fact my original account 2 role itself was unable to do so.