# AWS Dynamo DB - Copy table data across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

As per the document [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-cross-account-migration/)  S3+AWS Glue is one of the way of exporting data to S3 and then loading that to a DynamoDB table but the detailed steps are missing. Has anyone tried this or any other method to load data from a table in Account A to another table in Account B

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607592/copy-dynamodb-table-to-another-aws-account-without-s3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy dynamoDB table to another aws account without S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607592/copy-dynamodb-table-to-another-aws-account-without-s3)

Comment: I think this solution is suitable for a few thousand records since the run time would be less but in case of a few million records like 10M (my case) it would take up a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this Python + boto3:

- Different Regions

```py
import boto3


def migrate(source, target):
    dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
    dynamo_target_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

    dynamo_paginator = dynamo_client.get_paginator('scan')
    dynamo_response = dynamo_paginator.paginate(
        TableName=source,
        Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
        ReturnConsumedCapacity='NONE',
        ConsistentRead=True
    )
    for page in dynamo_response:
        for item in page['Items']:
            dynamo_target_client.put_item(
                TableName=target,
                Item=item
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    migrate('awesome-v1', 'awesome-v2')
```